# Strange behavior happening in Silverstripe backend?

Tags: silverstripe

All of a sudden whenever I try to click into a page in the silverstripe backend it initially displays like this, I was running SS 3.2, when this started happening I upgraded to 3.2.1 to see if that would fix the issues but nope:

[image]

Sometimes it displays this error message aswell: `[User Warning] Couldn't set response type to 404 because of output on line 1 of /Users/computername/Sites/themename/mysite/code/Pages/HomePage.php`

If I refresh it comes right but then if I go to add something through a `gridfield` after I click "create" it just goes to a blank screen but it still adds to the `Dataobject`.

Any idea whats happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorted this. I had a space or two in front of my `<?php` tag on the `HomePage.php` - Now it is working fine :)